# How to encrypt document root of Apache and all MySQL databases?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I need it encrypted and be decrypted just only when apache started, so this is the plan:

1. Boot computer.
2. Decrypt `/var/www` and mysql databases files.
3. Start apache.

So maybe its the path not to use mountion encrypted containers like truecrypt do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no problem with [eCryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs).

Create two partitions as eCryptfs and mount it after boot under /var/www and /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: Ok thanks! This is some encrypted containers such as truecrypt?

Comment: If you like to call it that way. Follow the Wikipedia article and the referenced documentation. But this is what you requested.

Comment: My little question about this situation, could we able to make Apache acts as a physical user and it automatically mount those locations? @mailq